# How to find a particular folder in volume mounted using Docker?

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-volume

I am using Neo4j using Docker image to up the database on Windows 10.

The command:

```
docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data neo4j
```

Now I want to delete some files in the folder named 'default.graphdb'.

I can enter the Docker container using command

```
docker exec -it <docker-container-id> /bin/bash
```

Please let me know where can I find the folder, and how to delete few files or the entire folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're mounting a local directory `$HOME/neo4j/data` to the `/data` directory in the container.
So, the content of the directory in the container will be synced with your local one.

There is actually no need to enter the container to view the content since if you delete something locally it will be reflected in the container as well.

But to reply fully, in the container it is exactly where you mapped when defining the volume, in `/data` :

```
$ docker exec -it neo4j_1 sh
# ls
LICENSE.txt  LICENSES.txt  NOTICE.txt  README.txt  UPGRADE.txt  bin  certificates  conf  data  import  lib  logs  metrics  plugins  run
# cd /data
# ls
databases  dbms  transactions
#
```